# Finding k largest elements in an array in O(1) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

Is it possible to have O(1) time complexity in find the k largest or smallest numbers in an array, by making a stack class with an auxiliary data structure to track k largest/smallest in every `push()` and `pop()`. Since retrieval is O(1), return k elements in a get method

Comment: `O(1)` is not possible. To retrieve `k` items, complexity would be at least `O(k)`. To get a constant (such as a pointer to an array holding the `k` items) would be possible.

Comment: For k == N, it is trivially O(1).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, can find out Kth largest element or smallest element by O(1) complexity only if your array is in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a well-known data structure you can find `Max-Heap` and `Min-Heap` useful. You can find more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

**Update**

As you have updated your question from max and min to k largest, you can preprocess your data into a sorted array and then insert new value using the insertion sort strategy. Then, you can report the `k` largest value in `O(k)` (and if the `k` is constant it would be in `O(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below link that discuss about the finding largest number
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/